# background-size:cover equivalent

Tags: html, css

if is there a way how to "imitate" the behavior of `background-size:cover;` (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover) with an `<img>` tag inside of a `<div>`. I want to have structure like this:

```
<div style="width:100%, height=30%">
    <img ng-src="{{data.imageData}}"/>
</div>
```

Sorry, if I am not very clear about the topic, I don't know, how to put it more clearly.

Comment: what about adding `img {width:100%; height:auto;}`

Comment: one of these depending on aspect ratio of image and its container: `{width: 100%; height: auto}` or `{width: auto; height: 100%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution but similar to @Moob.

```
div{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/14fs9ckL/)

Comment: That's exactly, I was looking for. @Moob's solution is working as well. I'd upvote, if I had enough rep. :)

Comment: This example doesn't center the image *or* make it fit vertically. Its just the same as defining the image width as 100%. See: https://jsfiddle.net/14fs9ckL/1/ for proof

Comment: Yep, I agree, you may be right, that this solution does not center the image or fit it vertically. If you look, i didn't require any of those. Another thing, it's not for a casual website, it's for an hybrid mobile app and I got some kind of a bug, when running both of solutions: sometimes, really just sometimes after my picture is shown on the page, that page became scrollable to the left/right. I have no idea why is that happening and it's happening only sometimes. I tried many times with the same picture, but I can't see any principle, why it behaves like that. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

You can accomplish this with `object-fit` and `object-position` property

Set it to `cover` and `top left` respectively

```
img {
  display: block;
  width:inherit;
  height: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top left;
}
```

**How these work**

These CSS3 properties are explained in css-tricks.com as follows

> The object-fit property defines how an element responds to the height
>   and width of its content box. It's intended for images, videos and
>   other embeddable media formats in conjunction with the object-position
>   property. Used by itself, object-fit lets us crop an inline image by
>   giving us fine-grained control over how it squishes and stretches
>   inside its box.

For detailed usage, refer [link1](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) and [link2](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-object-fit-object-position/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
$(window).load(function() {    

 var theWindow        = $(window),
     $bg              = $("#bg"),
     aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
              
 function resizeBg() {
  
  if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
      $bg
       .removeClass()
       .addClass('bgheight');
  } else {
      $bg
       .removeClass()
       .addClass('bgwidth');
  }
     
 }
                       
 theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

```css
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" id="bg" alt="">
```

See another alternatives:

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You can position the image absolutely within the `div`. Use `min-width` and `min-height` to make it at least as big as its container. Give it negative positioning and center it vertically and horizontally using `margin:auto`. Finally use `overflow:hidden` on the div to hide the overflow:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%; min-height:100%;
}
div {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
div img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:-100%;
    right:-100%;
    bottom:-100%;
    left:-100%;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>
```

It might be easier to see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb40mLq3/) as you can resize the panels to see it working.
http://jsfiddle.net/jb40mLq3/